# Why does Neeman avoid t-structures?

Tags: reference-request, triangulated-categories

I have a simple question: the book "Triangulated Categories" by A. Neeman aims to be an exhaustive reference about the whole (basic) theory of triangulated categories. So why there is only a single reference to t-structures (something I'm used to think as a basic topic in the theory of triangulated categories), in chapter 9 (whose topic is Bousfield localization)?

Comment: Different authors make different choices about what to include and what not to include (and this is a good thing overall). In general it seems unreasonable to expect authors to include everything that one might think of to include. Is there anything more to it than that?

Comment: Yes, I think there should be more to say: a reason above all the others is that Neeman seems to suggest that he *will* discuss t-structures in a subsequent section, but in the end he doesn't. Another (more philosophical) reason could be that you are not completely free to decide "what to include and what not to include" about a topic which is well-known and well-established. You are somewhat bound to what the entire community thinks is important, and if you want to go against this habit, it's a matter of intellectual honesty to state clearly this deviation from orthodoxy.

Comment: To put it more directly: would you trust a book on Linear Algebra with no mention of the spectral theorem?

Comment: I don't think it aims at being exhaustive, he even mentions something like that at the introduction, actually it's rather the contrary, there are no examples at all! In addition, most of the book is devoted to new material.

Comment: I don't really see the point of asking this question here, when you can easily try asking the author via email.

Comment: Deane may have a point: it's not clear that anyone besides the author can explain why the author made certain stylistic choices. (As an aside, I'm not entirely comfortable with OP's comment on being bound to do this or that, or speaking about "intellectual honesty" -- I'm just imagining how such remarks might be received by the author.)

Comment: @tetrapharmakon speaking as someone who taught a linear algebra course including the spectral theorem: sure, if the book was good at other things, perhaps doing more over finite fields or non-algebraically closed fields.

Comment: I mean, I like parts of Axler's book on linear algebra where he does away with determinants as much as possible, despite the fact that determinants are Traditional and Important. These things are not set in stone.

Comment: It's simply not true that the book "aims to be an exhaustive reference". In the introduction Neeman explains the genesis of the book and why it "treats a narrower range of topics than initially planned".

Comment: What should I do now? Try to explain my point or just let it go? All you guys are partly right, but I feel a subtle misunderstanding.

Comment: you can try to explain what you think it's a misunderstanding.

Comment: I maybe misunderstood the final aim of Neeman's book. But the author says explicitly in a couple of lines (just CTRL+F the pdf you find online!) that there will be a discussione about that topic. So, it's simply me asking: is the published version a prelimiary one? Did the author decide to avoid the discussion for a particular reason? I *could* ask him, but I suspected the reason was so blatant ("t-structures are subsumed by something else in chapter 9", or "the version you are reading is outdated and has been expanded: see here") that I could ask the users of the book first.

Comment: In my opinion t-structures are not a minor topic. People working in algebraic geometry, representation theory, stable homotopy theory, algebraic analysis all use this notion at some point; so I feel uncomfortable in reading a book which avoids to mention even a single result about them. The book "Down with determinants" goes against well-established practice for *pedagogical* purposes, and I think the author made this point extremely clear along the book. This is a completely different situation: something which I feel fundamental is missing, and nobody told me why.

Comment: "[On the planet of Tlon, books] of a philosophical nature invariably include both the thesis and the antithesis, the rigorous pro and con of a doctrine. A book which does not contain its counterbook is considered incomplete." 
People writing books about Mathematics have to respond, before anything else, to a principle of clarity and intellectual honesty towards their readers. I compeltely agree that everybody is free to write whatever he wants in whichever way he wants;

Comment: [continue] but we aren't speaking about Philosophy here, choices about what to neglect and privilege have to be *motivated* in order to develop in the reader a critic attitude (forming opinions is the most important thing we seek in reading a book). Halmos said "Don't read it, fight it"? Well, then I'm fighting, questioning this choice of the author: there must be a deeper reason than "I had no time to conclude that part" to motivate it. And there must be something I can learn, from this choice, were it only a trivial statement about human behaviour, or (better) some Mathematics.

Comment: I don't see why t-structures are a must in a triangulated category book. It's an important topic, of course, but not comparable to determinants.

Comment: I dare not judge what's the main aim of Newman's triangulated book, but I'd say it's more connected to Brown repeatability. It has a basic part, but it's not a basic book.

Answer (score 15):

I just ran into him at the kitchen sink and asked him your question. He said the book was already too long to include anything on t-structures. He had originally intended to write a second volume which would cover them, but he never got started on it.